# Pseudoscalar-like objects

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors

As far as I understand, a [pseudoscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) is an object that behaves like a scalar but changes parity under parity inversion. An example would be the [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)
$$A\cdot (B \times C)$$
The pseudoscalar property of the scalar triple product exhibits itself under permutations of its operands ($A, B, C$). I'm wondering whether there exists an object which I shall denote $q$ such that
$$q A = -A q$$
$$q A q^{-1} = -A$$
for some vector $A$. Such object would be analogous to psuedoscalars, except in commutivity instead of parity inversion. I'm aware of [Grassmann numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) that exhibit
$$\theta_i \theta_j = - \theta_j \theta_i$$
$$\theta_i^2=0$$
but that isn't what I'm after. I'm specifically wondering about some $q$ that acts on vectors $A$.

Comment: I think, when you say "some" you actually mean "every." And your "objects" are probably (invertible) elements of some associative ${\mathbb R}$-algebra $A$ containing the given vector space $V$ as a linear subspace. I do not know what else you want to assume about $A$.